# MVC routing more than one controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using MVC 4.0 and I am trying to add a route for each controller.

Well, my first controller is called CustomersController. The route that I've
added is:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Customer",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{IdCustomer}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Index", IdCustomer = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

When I am running the application, I get the following links in the Index page(List):

```
http://localhost:6838/Customers/Create/5
http://localhost:6838/Customers/Edit/5
http://localhost:6838/Customers/Details/5
http://localhost:6838/Customers/Delete/5
```

Ok, great! It's what I am looking for, but, now start my problem. I added another
controller, called ItemsController (with the same actions - Create/Edit/Details/Delete) then I tried to add the same route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Item",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{IdItem}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Items", action = "Index", IdItem = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

But now the result is different... I am getting the following links:

```
    http://localhost:6838/Items/Create?IdItem=1
    http://localhost:6838/Items/Edit?IdItem=1
    http://localhost:6838/Items/Detail?IdItem=1
    http://localhost:6838/Items/Delete?IdItem=1
```

WHY.. WHY :'( it isn't working? Why it's working only for the first route and not
for the new one just added?!

Best regards,
Dan

Comment: Your routes are way too generic. Why are you still using `{controller}` when these actions are specific to `Customers` & `Items` (per the id's name)? You should be using `Customers/{action}/{IdCustomer}` or `Items/{action}/{IdItem}`. Remember that URL generation is a sequential test. The first matching URL the parser finds it will use (so in this case the customer url is used).

Comment: It's the first time that I am using routes.. I had never used it before. It's complicated to me to understand what you mean.

Comment: Dan, think of it like this. You set those two routes up server-side, then me (as a client) send `Items/Edit/6`. MVC would look at your `Customers` route and say "Hmm, they didn't name it "IdCustomer` all I have is the ID "5" but everything seems to match--let's use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a synopsis of my answer, your routes are too vague. You need to be more specific to get a better result (especially if you're not using the route by name). I would go for something like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Customers",
    url: "Customers",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Index" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomerDetails",
    url: "Customer/{IdCustomer}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Details", IdItem = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomerEdit",
    url: "Customer/{IdCustomer}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit", IdItem = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
/* and so on (then move on to Items) */
```

Now you can reference them by name and also eliminate a lot of the rudimentary information you normally provide (like action and controller details). It also makes updating a link easier down the road as the route is named and not an explicit controller/action.

```
@Html.RouteLink("Edit Customer", "CustomerEdit", new { IdCustomer = model.Id });
```

You can now make this in a different area or have another controller handle it later by changing your route defined and all your RouteLinks could remain the same.